# API Service Form is failing

Tags: youtube-api

im trying to finish the YouTube API Services compliance review for our iOS app.
We resolved all open requests from YouTube a while ago. Sadly we cant reach our YouTube Service compliance review editor anymore. Applying again fails always with the comment that we submitted an irrelevant form. The Google support sent us here to get help.

Can somebody of the Google YouTube team give us further instruction how to resolve this issue.

Thanks :)
Sven

Comment: AFAIK Google support team doesn't operate anymore on YouTube API StackOverflow tags. May I ask you what features from the YouTube Data API you are using ?

Comment: iOS YouTube video upload